# Scrapy inside java?

Tags: java, python, scrapy

Is it possible to use Scrapy from within a Java project?

With Jython for example, or maybe "indirect" solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt you can run twisted under jython and scrapy is based on twisted. 
Not sure what you want to do but I recommend to run scrapyd and use the web service interface to communicate with java.
Can you give us more details on what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Should be, but have you considered using something like [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/)?

Comment: Is JSoup new? Last time i was doing this (some time ago!), TagSoup was the best parse-anything parser, and Neko was a good strict one.

Comment: AFAIK jsoup cant handle AJAX pages. And Scrapy seems to be very promising project. I read thah Jython not pass Python libs written on C to work with them within Java - and i wonder - is Scrapy use those?

Comment: there is no comparison between scrapy and jsoup , jsoup is primarily made for Parsing , while Scrapy made for crawling , Parsing is its secondary function.