# Using Scrapy inside Java?

Tags: java, python, scrapy

This is a follow up question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13532170/scrapy-inside-java):

Basically, I have a java applet that is running in a browser, and I want it to scrape a few pages. Is there a way to get all the benefits of python-driven [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) using Java?

(And to throw an extra spanner in the works, I'm developing on a Windows machine... this is my first time trying to use Python, so I have no idea what the limitations are when considering using them together. Perhaps there is a better way to scrape using Java?)

Answer (score 3):

As in your previous question. Jython cannot be used since scrapy is a pure python.Typically you would use jython to access Java libraries,not the other way around.

### **Python answer**

To answer your original question, I would develop my scraping application separately using python and have an intermediate web service layer to communicate it with the Java applet.You can implement the web service listener in python which listens for requests and then consume that web service in Java applet.

No other solution can guarantee you stability,since there is no standard way of communicating with python and java, I would definitely take the web service route.

### **Java answer**

[Apache Nutch](http://nutch.apache.org/) seems to be a good starting point and it is much more than just a scraping library(P.S : I do not have first hand experience in it).It would seem like an overkill, but since your application is already in Java,taking this option seems better.

In the end it highly depends upon your requirements. Python scrapy might be quicker to get it up and running and if you want to implement a full blown web crawler then Apache Nutch seems to be a good option.

Comment: This answer is wrong. Jython can be used to run Python scripts in the JVM.

Comment: @suriv : Please read my answer clearly.I meant scrapy cannot be run inside java since it is pure python, not jython itself. What part was not clear ?

Comment: You can call python from java using jython.    The libraries that jython will have trouble with are ones that use call into CPython itself (the implementation).   Pure-python libraries are exactly the kind of you can run.